# how to retrieve results after api call which is returning a promise

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I have a module that invokes a service

```
let getData =  () => fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => (getData = json));

export {getData };
```

I try to log to console the result (and put it on an HTML page) like this

```
import { getData } from "./api";


 const app = document.querySelector("#target");
    let data = getData()
      .then(res => res.map(r => r.title).join("\n"))
      .then(res => (data = res));
      console.log(data);
      app.innerHTML = data;
```

However, I get an unresolved promise like this [object Promise]

I've tried a few variations which also don't work

```
// none of these work don't work

// .then(async res => data = await res);
// .then(res => (data = Promise.resolve(res)));
```

Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you shouldn't use the second `then` in `getData` - that's the result, and it reassigns your variable. Then change some other things in your code - syntax errors and wrong methods mostly:

```js
let getData = () => fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts").then(response => response.json());

const app = document.querySelector("#target");
getData()
  .then(res => res.map(r => r.title).join("<br>"))
  .then(res => app.innerHTML = res);
```

```html
<p id="target"></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

i think you have to 'return' response.json() and then exec another then()
and also is better to include cathc to see problems

read 
Making fetch requests
https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

```
    let getData = () => fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
.then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
const app = document.querySelector("#target");
getData()
 .then(res => res.map(r => app.innerHTML += r.title));
```